# Why are there religious restrictions on women?

Tags: belief, rituals, women, widow

From what i have seen women are more religious than men.But there are many prohibitions on them when it comes to participating in religious acts.Restrictions that are imposed upon men are far less in comparison.

Also,widows are not allowed to be part of any auspicious ceremony.

What is the basis of imposing such religious restrictions on women & in particular on the widows?

Comment: JH i have edited ur question..pls see if i have done justice to ur original question or not..feel free to edit it again if u are not satisfied with my edit..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because of the male chauvinistic people in the society who have snatched all the religious right from the women including that of the vedic studies and vedic rituals etc.

In the recent centuries we saw that widow's suffered a lot of torture after the death of husband. At some places they were tonsured, they were kept isolated and forced not to wear make-up or jewelry etc. which is unethical.

scriptures allow widows to remarry if they wish. (Rg Veda. X.18.8) (Ath Veda XVIII.3.2) Some Sutras allow a widow to marry her brother-in-law which is also stated in the Mahabharata though marrying brother-in law is not compulsory. Atharva Veda prescribes a ritual (ajA paNchodana) for lifelong union with the new husband. (AV  9.3.27). In MBH there are reference of widow remarriage. Arjuna had a son with the widowed daughter of Naga king airAvata. UgrAyudha wanted to marry Satyavati, the widow of shantanu.

In terms of rituals, both widow and widowers have almost same rules. There is no partiality between a widow and a widower (vidhura). A widow can perform the pArvana shraddha at sacred places during occasions such as mahalaya. She is not debarred from performing Vriddhi shraddha (ref. Shraddha manjari).

There are no injunctions in the vedas or scriptures like MBH or Puranas where we see widows getting tonsured hence such practices are later day additions. the Do's and Dont's are almost same for both wife and husband.

Comment: Thanx.. for giving this information.. can give some more detail about these topic or suggest me to source where I can get more information..

Comment: what kind of information you want ? and how can I share with you ?

Comment: In your answer,  `both widow and widowers have almost same rules` so, I want more about it.

Comment: @JH_ like one cannot undertake vedic rites and sacrifice in absence of spouse

Comment: Downvoted because of feminist conspiratorial statement: "It is because of the male chauvinistic people in the society who have snatched all the religious right from the women including that of the vedic studies and vedic rituals etc."

Comment: @Ikshvaku no problem the fact is still the same that vedas have no such restrictions

Comment: @RakeshJoshi No one denies Brahmavadini women from learning Vedas, but how many women become Brahmavadini? None.

Comment: @Ikshvaku its for any person desirous of learning vedas. And how do you know there is no brahmavadini now?